# How to perform unsigned to signed conversion in Java?

Tags: java, type-conversion, signed

Say I read these bytes: "6F D4 06 40" from an input device. The number is a longitude reading in MilliArcSeconds format. The top bit (0x80000000) is basically always zero and is ignored for this question.

I can easily convert the bytes to an *unsigned* integer: 1876166208

But how do I convert that unsigned value into its final form of 31-bit signed-integer?

So far all I've come up with is:

1. if value & 0x40000000 then it's actually negative, need to convert it
2. If it's negative, strip the top bit and do something with the remaining bits...

So I can tell if it's a negative number, but in order to know what value the negative number is, I have to do something with the remaining bits - a one's compliment? How do I do that in Java?

Another way to put the question is, how do I convert an unsigned integer into a 31-bit signed integer in Java?

Thank you!

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question in my answer.  Can you say what you want the value of the signed integer to be, based on your example input?  You never said that.

Comment: Input: "6F D3 FD 45". Output: Approximately -75.366465. I say approximate because I found a spot and stayed there to collect data and at the same time measured the location with a GPS. So the longitude above (-75.366465) should be close, but probably not exactly, the same value as the above hex bytes converted to a signed integer (and MAS to Degrees conversion performed). *I'm trying to find a way to go from the hex bytes into a signed int using Java*

Comment: MAS to Degrees: divide by 3,600,000.

Comment: Getting close... Actual reading with "negative bit" stripped: "2F D3 FD 45"... compare this to the expected MAS value of -75.366465 of "10 2C 00 EA"... First 22 bits match if I flip 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 (XOR). I think that might be the trick - need to flip all the bits... I can do that with an XOR...

Comment: @Mark - you are correct. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on what the lower 31 bits of your input are meant to represent.

```
int input = 0x6FD40640 & 0x7FFFFFFF; //strip top bit; only here for clarity
```

Unsigned input: `0x6FD40640 == 1876166208`

### Two's complement (desired output: -271317440)

A **two's complement** integer is one where -1 has all bits set, and lower negatives number count down from there.  The first bit still acts as a sign bit.

```
1000 -> -8
1001 -> -7
...
1110 -> -2
1111 -> -1
0000 ->  0
0001 ->  1
```

If the lower 31 bits represent a two's complement integer, then I think you should just be able to do this:

```
input = (input << 1) >> 1;
```

That's because Java stores integers in two's complement internally: all we do is shift left and then shift back right (signed) so that the sign bit is picked up and the integer goes from 31 bits to 32 bits.

### One's complement (desired output: -802424384)

A **one's complement** number representation is one where the first bit is a dedicated sign bit, and the remaining bits represent the magnitude.  The lower bits of -100 will be the same as the lower bits of 100:

```
 1111 -> -7
 1110 -> -6
 ...
 1001 -> -1
 1000 -> -0 (anomoly)
 0000 ->  0
 0001 ->  1
```

If the lower 31 bits represent a **one's complement** integer (that is, a sign bit followed by 30 bits representing an unsigned magnitude), then you need to convert it into two's complement so that Java extracts the value properly.  To do this you just need to extract the lower 30 bits and multiply by -1:

```
if ( input & 0x40000000 ) {
   input = (input & 0x3FFFFFFF) * -1;
}
```

You said in the question's comments that after converting to degrees (dividing by 3600000) you get around -75.36.  **When I divide -271317440 by 3600000 I get -75.36595555555556**, so I'm guessing your input format is two's complement, so my first and original answer was correct.

Comment: Looks like it'll do the trick.  Not sure `& 0x7FFFFFFF` is necessary though.

Comment: It seems like the &7fffffff and the left/right shift do the same thing (drop the leftmost top bit)? I'm working on getting some sample data so we can test this

Comment: @Alison: no that was just there to demonstrate that the input was only the lower 31 bits, and that the high bit is irrelevant.  The second line is what I was trying to show, but Brad hasn't confirmed whether that's the desired output or not.

Comment: @Brad: just anding by `&7FFFFFFF` will simply clear the top bit.  This shifts to the left, but shifts to the right in a sign-extended manner.  In other words, it fills the first bit with the second bit. But again I'd need to see what your desired output is...I don't know what the 31 lower bits are supposed to represent.

Comment: Why is this answer getting up-voted? It doesn't address the question at all. Please re-read the question!

Answer (score 0):

Reading an unsigned integer as signed is a matter of identifying whether the most significant bit (negative flag) is set, and if so, flip all bits of the number (thus clearing the most significant bit, and switching the number to its negative representation. When performing the aforementioned process you must also make note of the fact that the resultant number is a negative.

```
// Convert the hex bytes to an unsigned integer
long MAS = Integer.ValueOf("6F D4 06 40".replace (" ",""),16);
boolean isLongitudeNegative = false;

// Is the negative-bit set? If so, strip it and toggle all bits.
if (MAS & 0x40000000 > 0) {
    // then it's negative, so strip the negative bit and flip all the other bits
    MAS ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    // Throw away the unused bit.
    MAS &= 0x7FFFFFFF;
    isLongitudeNegative = true;
}

// Now convert from MAS to degrees minutes seconds
String DMS = convertMASToDMS(isLongitudeNegative,MAS);
```

Comment: Sorry for the outbursts. Did this answer end up doing the trick for your requirements?  If so feel free to accept it.  Only suggestion is that you might find `MAS = ~MAS` to be a more clear way of toggling the bits of MAS.  So given this solution, I assume the lower 31 bits of the input represent a 31-bit one's complement integer, and you're trying to extract that value?  Is that the problem you were trying to solve?

Comment: Check my answer again.  I'm pretty sure my original answer was correct.  When I apply my transformation to your sample input and then divide by 3600000 I get -75.369555 which is your expected output.  When I do your transformation I get -222 which doesn't jive.