# MySQL aggregate function return value to JAVA POJO Class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using MySQL and want to fire a query like `select count(*) from table`.Then I want to 
store the return value in a `JAVA Pojo`.

MySQL query returns signed or unsigned integer but Java only supports signed integer so 
how can i handle this error?

ProjectListModel class is  a simple bean not a hibernate entity. It's more like:

```
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ProjectListModel.class));
```

ProjectListModel contain a field `public int rowCount` which I am going to store the return value.

Comment: What error? Store the value in a long field, not an int. The possible range of an unsigned int in MySQL exceeds the max value of an int in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the value in a try catch block which handles `NumberFormatException` and if it catches use sth. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935304/how-to-perform-unsigned-to-signed-conversion-in-java)